# Dynamically add a note to apache load balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I have 1 apache which distributes the request among various tomcats. I want to add more tomcats to this load balancer so that now the routed requests can also go to this new tomcat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apache as a load balancer ? Apache eats LOTS of RAM... for a load balancer you'd be better off with HAproxy or Nginx.